# D3 Zooming issue for Network Map in V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am having an issue with zooming functionality in Map.
The zooming in happening for the whole SVG element but not for bubbles and lines.

Using below code to resolve but not working properly, where I am doing the mistake?

```
var svg = d3.select(this.domNode).append("svg")
      .attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height",height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
   svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}))
.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left +"," +margin.top+")")
      .on("click", function(d) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains('nodes')) {
            me.clearSelections();
            me.endSelections();
            return true;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
     })
;
```

Now trying to use below:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .translate(projection.translate())
    .scale(projection.scale())
    .scaleExtent([height, 8 * height])
    .on("zoom", zoomed); 

var svg = d3.select(this.domNode).append("svg")
      .attr("width",width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height",height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .call(zoom)
.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left +"," +margin.top+")")

;

function zoomed() {
  projection.translate(d3.event.translate).scale(d3.event.scale);
  g.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);
  g.selectAll(".place-label").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6; })
   ;


  g.selectAll("circle").attr("cx", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[0];
           })
           .attr("cy", function(d) {
                   return projection([d.longitude, d.latitude])[1];
           });
  g.selectAll("line")
        .attr("distance", 10)

//        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
//        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr('x1', function(d) { return projection([d.Slongitude, d.Slatitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return projection([d.Slongitude, d.Slatitude])[1]; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return projection([d.Tlongitude, d.Tlatitude])[0]; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return projection([d.Tlongitude, d.Tlatitude])[1]; })
        ;


}
```

You can have a look at the [video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bzh84D0DhvsCSzhpdDFqMm5RREk), what is the exact issue.

Comment: Does anyone having solution for this. pls, let me know.It will be appreciable.

Comment: Hi @Oliver Houston Do you have any solution for this requirement?

Comment: Can anyone pls help me on this..

Comment: did found any solution buddy?

Comment: @InzmamGujjar No Buddy..Still searching. not getting how to do that in V4.Can u help me on this?